# How do I install ImageMagick for MinGW on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, bash, git, imagemagick, mingw

Well... I have already installed MinGW32 (I don't know the version - installed in a folder named Git 2.4.4.2) on Windows 7, and I want to install ImageMagick to run some scripts like the follow:

```
echo " Creating different dimensions of "$1" ..."

convert $1 -resize 67% dir1/$1
convert $1 -resize 50% dir2/$1
convert $1 -resize 33% dir3/$1
mv $1 dir0/$1

echo " Done"
```

As far as I searched on Google there is not a clear detailed guide how to install it. I downloaded this ImageMagick version: [ImageMagick-i686-pc-mingw32.tar.gz](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

From the [official ImageMagick site guide](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) I go up to the first step *Unpack the distribution with this command:*

```
tar xvzf ImageMagick-i686-pc-mingw32.tar.gz
```

and I get as result a folder ImageMagick-6.8.5.
So far so good. But the next step *Next configure and compile ImageMagick:*

```
cd ImageMagick-6.8.5
./configure
make
```

I get *bash: ./configure: No such file or directory*.

Here is my photo:

[image: Configure fail]

This is `ls -l` results:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

I have only installed MinGw32, not MSYS (as I read in a not so detailed guide).

Comment: why arent you using the windows version of imagemagick?

Comment: the scenario says to use this way, and I want to try this way

Comment: Do you have a `./configure` in that directory? What are it's file permissions?

Comment: @DavidPostill I edit question and post the screenshot of the `ls -l`.. Hope this help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to install ImageMagick to run some scripts

> I download this ImageMagick version [ImageMagick-i686-pc-mingw32.tar.gz](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Your link (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) is a link to the ImageMagick **binary** releases.

> From the [official ImageMagick site guide](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) I go up to the first step Unpack the distribution with this command

Your link (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) is a link to the "Install from Source" page.

That page tell you how to build and install from the source.

> I get bash: ./configure: No such file or directory.

You downloaded the binary not the source.

---

#### I want to install the binary

Go back to the page you download the **binary** from (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

Then follow the instructions on that page to install the binary you downloaded.

---

#### I want to build and install from the source

If you want to build from the source then download the **source** from the links on https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

Then follow the rest of the instruction on that page.

Answer (score 5):

if you use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) just open the mingw-console and type in:

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -S base-devel
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libpng
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick
```